# db_select group by of union

Tags: database

I'm quite new to drupal ad I've some problem with parsing a query throught the API:

```
    SELECT t.pg,p.classe, sum(t.punti) AS punti, sum(t.vinte) AS vinte, sum(t.perse) AS perse, (sum(t.vinte)+sum(t.perse)) AS giocate
    FROM(
        SELECT sid, team_member_a_1 AS pg, punti_team_a AS punti, 1 AS vinte, 0 AS perse
        FROM `webform_views_unusual_arena__risultati_6` AS t1
        WHERE tipologia_risultato = 0
            AND vincente = 0
        UNION
        SELECT sid, team_member_a_2 AS pg, punti_team_a AS punti, 1 AS vinte, 0 AS perse
        FROM `webform_views_unusual_arena__risultati_6` AS t1
        WHERE tipologia_risultato = 0
            AND vincente = 0
    ) AS t
    JOIN webform_views_i_miei_pg_1 AS p ON t.pg = p.nome_pg
    GROUP BY pg
```

But I can't find any documentation about a subquery or how to add field like "1 AS vinte"

EDIT
Thank's to Tenken this is the code I used.

```
$subquery_1 = db_select('webform_views_unusual_arena__risultati_6', 't')
    ->condition('t.tipologia_risultato', 0, '=')
    ->condition('t.vincente', 0,'=')
    ->fields('t', array('sid'));
$subquery_1->addExpression('team_member_a_1', 'pg');
$subquery_1->addExpression('punti_team_a', 'punti');
$subquery_1->addExpression(1, 'vinte');
$subquery_1->addExpression(0, 'perse');
$subquery_2 = db_select('webform_views_unusual_arena__risultati_6', 't')
    ->condition('t.tipologia_risultato', 0, '=')
    ->condition('t.vincente', 0,'=')
    ->fields('t', array('sid'));
$subquery_2->addExpression('team_member_a_2', 'pg');
$subquery_2->addExpression('punti_team_a', 'punti');
$subquery_2->addExpression(1, 'vinte');
$subquery_2->addExpression(0, 'perse');
$query = $subquery_1->union($subquery_2);

$query->addExpression('sum(vinte)', 'vinte');
$query->addExpression('sum(perse)', 'perse');
$query->addExpression('sum(punti)', 'punti');       
$query->groupBy('pg');
$query->orderBy('punti', 'DESC');
```

Hope it will help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [WEALTH OF DOCUMENTATION on Dynamic Queries in D7](http://drupal.org/node/310075) ... it will answer EVERYTHING :) .... in all seriousness :).

To add `SUM(blah) as foo` you want to add an [SQL Expression to your Select clause](http://drupal.org/node/1848358) with `addExpression()`.

To add `Group by COLNAME` you want to use `groupBy()` with your db_selection, see [group by docs](http://drupal.org/node/1848364).

Comment: I already tried to group by as you suggest, but i keep on getting the error message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.pg' in 'group statement'

Comment: `fields` go in the `fields()` array. I've never used `addField()` like that, I always use `addExpression()` which your not using at all ... see comments here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddField/7

I speak and write english and spanish. In my opinion you should try to make your PHP code 1 language and not two (or 3) ... it's easier for people to understand.

Comment: You were totally right!
I will update my question with the final code.